# Displaying a model property as a dropdown list in view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm working on a user management system in asp.net mvc, where I display all my users in a grid using KendoUI.
However, I have a List of user roles, which I need to display as a dropdown in my edit view. Since my view is generated based on my model, I'm not really sure how to accomplish this.

Here's my model:

```
  public class UserModel
    {
        #region Properties
        [Display(Name = @"Username")]
        [Required]
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = @"E-mail")]
        [EmailAddress]
        [Required]
        public string Email { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Phone { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Company { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = @"Password")]
        [Required]
        public string PasswordHash { get; set; }
        [Display(Name= @"Roles")]
        public List<string> UserRoles { get; set; }
        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public string UserRoleIcon { get; set; }
        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public string UserRoleIconInverted { get; set; }

        #endregion

        public UserModel()
        {

        }
     ...omitted some content

  }
```

Here's my KendoGrid:

```
    @(Html.Kendo().Grid<Project.Name.Models.User.UserModel>()
            .Name("grid")
            .Columns(columns =>
            {
                columns.Bound(p => p.UserName);
                columns.Bound(p => p.Name);
                columns.Bound(p => p.Email);
                columns.Bound(p => p.Phone);
                columns.Bound(p => p.UserRoles);
                columns.Command(command => { command.Edit(); }).Width(160);
            })
            .ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Create())
            .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp))
            .Pageable()
            .Sortable()
            .Scrollable()
            .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:430px;" })
            .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                .Ajax()
                .PageSize(20)
                .Events(events => events.Error("error_handler"))
                .Model(model => model.Id(p => p.UserName))
                .Create(update => update.Action("EditingPopup_Create", "UserManagement"))
                .Read(read => read.Action("EditingPopup_Read", "UserManagement"))
                .Update(update => update.Action("EditingPopup_Update", "UserManagement"))
            )
        )
```

And finally, here's what my new user dialogue looks like. I'm trying to add a dropdown or multiselect (as a user can have several roles) at the bottom of this list, allowing me to set or update the wanted roles to the new (or edited) user.

[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you check KendoUI demo page about custom editor functions (http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/grid/editing-custom.html)? I think that what they do with Category is pretty similar to what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thanks @OnaBai:) I've looked into that, and contacted Kendo on their forums as well. Can't seem to get it working using editor templates :/

Answer (score 0):

My understandning is that you need to a pre populated drop down on the edit screen.Since I was working on something similar, let me explain how I did it. I am not using Kendo but a similar solution might work.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedUserRole, new SelectList(UserModel.userRoles), "Choose One", new { @class = "dropdownliststyle" })
```

The `UserModel.userRoles` being a static variable which contained the values that I need to populate.

Hope this helped!

Comment: Hi Nanda! Thanks for your suggestion, but the edit dialogue is auto generated based on model values, and is a part of the Kendo component, so I don't really have much control over it. That's why I was hoping it was possible to autogenerate it based on a model attribute or something like that :/

Comment: Oh okay. What if the property it was bound to was a list or array, just shooting in the dark here!

Comment: Problem is that "model" does not seem to be available. Take a look at this example: http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/grid/editing-custom.html (Just select "ASP.NET MVC" in the editor and then the cshtml file). Problem for me is that my model contains a List<string>, which does not want to translate to a auto-generated dropdown or multiselect.

Answer (score 0):

As I found in http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/framework/model#methods-Model.define

> The available options are "string", "number", "boolean", "date".

One workaround is to add a string field in your model (ex. Role) and use custom validation to validate entered string with your list of roles.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this by creating a custom template for the crud view in the popup.
For more details, see [this post in the Telerik forums](http://www.telerik.com/forums/need-help-adding-a-multiselect-or-dropdown-in-my-grid).